# Can't run npm install as it does not contain a package.json file

Tags: angular, npm

Here is my story: I wanted to upgrade my local @angular-cli version. I did it and it caused a lot of problems (Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc' etc.), because of that, I tried many different ways to solve the problem, but it didn't work. Then I moved to another project and when I run `ng serve` it had a problem about Node Sass. I tried to solve it but now it says 
`The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.`

And I cannot run `npm install` as it says:
Could not install from "node_modules/base-env/resolve-file@github:jonschlinkert/..." as it does not contain a package.json file.

How on earth can I solve this problem?

Comment: try deleting the package-lock.json

Comment: @Adapttoweb Now I have another error: 
`ERROR in node_modules/angularx-social-login/src/providers/facebook-login-provider.d.ts(10,35): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.`

Comment: `ng serve` has to be run inside a folder where your `angular.json` file is

Answer (score 0):

This happens because time ago, Angular projects were defined by an `angular-cli.json` file. In latest versions, that file has been renamed in `angular.json`. If you only updated your cli version without changing any code, then the script is looking for a `angular.json` but, since it doesn't find any, it throws an error stating that that's not an angular project.

To solve it, you can run:

> ng update @angular/cli

Which will migrate all your configuration towards the new format.

If this doesn't work too, the easiest way to solve any problem, by experience, is to run again

> ng new <project-name>

In a new folder, and copy/paste the *src/app* content

Comment: I solved the error by removing package-lock.json file and then running npm install. But I have another problem now: `ERROR in node_modules/angularx-social-login/src/providers/facebook-login-provider.d.ts(10,35): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.` Have you got any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Yes. `npm remove angularx-social-login` and `npm install angularx-social-login`, so you will install the latest version. That error means that the file was created for a previous version of typescript, but I guess that the author will have updated it over time

Comment: Now it says that `Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.`

Comment: Are you modifying the npm packages directly?

Answer (score 0):

ng update added

```
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8ng update @angular/material@8.8"
```

to my package.json. removing this row fixed my problem